# apache config with static site and django wsgi app

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I need to host a static web site along with a Django application server on the same Apache virtual host.  The static site needs to be accessible from the root url (/), while the application server should be invoked only when the url begins with /service.  I need to use mod_wsgi to integrate the Django service with Apache.  Ideally, I could configure the two sites with something like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /service service.wsgi
Alias / "/var/www/"
```

However, Apache prioritizes Alias before WSGIScriptAlias, and hence all requests end up at the static web site.  How can I get the behavior that I want.  I've tried using mod_redirect, but haven't been successful.

Comment: More of a server configuration question; better suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
Alias / "/var/www/"
```

Set DocumentRoot for the default static file root.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Also be aware that the target path for the WSGIScriptAlias directive has to be an absolute path and can't just be 'service.wsgi'.

Comment: Thanks much.  I can't believe it was that easy, but it works perfectly. I can throw out all the ineffective mod_rewrite rules I've tried.